# Not able to kill my Redshift locked Query PID running for 18 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am not Able to kill my redshift locked query which has been locked for 18 hours now

```
select *,datediff(s,txn_start,getdate())/86400||' days '||datediff(s,txn_start,getdate())%86400/3600||' hrs '||datediff(s,txn_start,getdate())%3600/60||' mins '||datediff(s,txn_start,getdate())%60||' secs'
from svv_transactions where lockable_object_type='transactionid' and pid<>pg_backend_pid() order by 3 desc
```

Locke Results

```
mydate,dev,431155629,89018,2022-01-19 13:01:39.397709,ExclusiveLock,transactionid,,true,0 days 19 hrs 1 mins 29 secs
```

I have tried few following commands

```
select pg_terminate_backend(89018) 

cancel 89018 'Long-running query';
     
 SET query_group TO 'superuser'; 
     
     CANCEL 89018
```

But I still get 1 in return when I try to kill that query

I am not able to kill it for long time, Please let me know

I have also tried using 'STV_LOCKS' but it doesn't show me locked queries
So I am not able to figure out how I can

Comment: Maybe you can consider reaching out to AWS support team so you can get expert advise on how to solve this man>!

Comment: We rebooted the Redshift cluster, solved the issue for now.

Comment: glad to hear you solved your problem. Posting an answer to let other devs/ops about potential solution!

Comment: I agree , But rebooting doesn't sounds to be the right answer to solve, that's more like a brute force approach. I will reach out to Amazon to see what can be done using their console to solve such issues in future

Comment: haha, its a common know magic trick :D

Comment: @AllanChua HAHA , I know right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can consider reaching out to AWS support team so you can get expert advise on how to solve this man? Posting this answer to let other people know that reboots can also help